# Create com object from dll manually

Tags: delphi, com

I'm using a code that calls a `CoCreateInstance` with a `GUID` to create an object (a scripter)
Is it possible to create the same COM object without using the `GUID`, by loading manually the `DLL`? if yes, how to find the `DLL`, how to know the name of the function creating the object ?

Comment: Yes, if there's a flat API export. What is the object you are using (that scripter)?

Comment: jscript.dll, guid : {f414c260-6ac0-11cf-b6d1-00aa00bbbb58}

Comment: Aha, the [IActiveScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/winscript/reference/iactivescript) interface.

Comment: Why do you need to load the DLL manually? You should be using `CoCreateInstance()`. The alternative (that Stijn suggests) just duplicates what `CoCreateInstance()` does internally, just without a Registry check. And you can use [Registration-Free COM Activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) to accomplish that without avoiding `CoCreateInstance()`.

Comment: the dll is different among desktops, and i have different behaviors, even bugs, i'd like to provide the dll in the directory application and to use the same on evey computers.

Comment: You can't redistribute that library.

Answer (score 0):

No.

One COM Server, be it DLL or EXE or something, usually hosts the implementations for many different, while interconnected, interfaces.

So you will find the DLL of your server, but you would still have to tell the server which of its many GUIDs it should materialize for you.

See DllGetClassObject entry point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760.aspx

To find the COM server EXE or DLL check the registry keys like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000108-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}\InprocServer32`

Then, your specific library may duplicate their primary COM API with the additional non-COM API. Then that non-COM API would be the one you can use in the way you describe. If it provides extra means for it.

However in terms of generic COM standard it is not possible, COM is built exactly around GUIDs.

Comment: Registration free COM allows this

Comment: ....would still ask for the class to create. And class is GUID. Example: Microsoft XMLLite.DLL API

Answer (score 0):

To create an object instance straight from the DLL, provided you know it's exact path, this code should work:

```
type
  T_DGCO = function(const CLSID, IID: TGUID; var Obj): HResult; stdcall; //DllGetClassObject
var
  p: T_DGCO;
  f: IClassFactory;
  x: IMyObject; //replace by an interface of choice
begin
  p := GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(FullPathToDLL), 'DllGetClassObject');
  Win32Check(p <> nil);
  OleCheck(p(CLASS_MyObject, IClassFactory, f));
  OleCheck(f.CreateInstance(nil, IMyObject, x));
  x.Hello('World'); //or whatever your object does
end;
```

Comment: Calling the parameterless `RaiseLastOSError()` if either `DllGetClassObject()` or `CreateInstance()` fail is wrong, since they don't use `SetLastError()` to report errors, they return `HRESULT` error codes instead. Save the error code to a variable and pass it to the overloaded `RaiseLastOSError()` that takes an error code as input. Or better, use `OleCheck()` instead (and `Win32Check()` for `LoadLibrary()`/`GetProcAddress()`).

Comment: this answer does not address another requirement, quote: create the same COM object **without using the GUID** - `CLASS_MyObject, IClassFactory` are not declared?

Comment: I don't know of any other way to get to a class factory instance from the DLL than asking for it with the identifying GUID... The fact that the specified DLL will be used probably is more important than avoiding the GUID altogether.